# WebSphere Commerce OpenLaszlo API extend class

Tags: websphere, openlaszlo, commerce

I'm quite new in Open Laszlo API for WebSphere Commerce. So i need a piece of advice.
I have a file in restricted called wcfBusinessObjectEditor. In this class i want to change some small parts (let's say a color). I know that is forbidden to change something in here, so i copy this file as wcfBusinessObjectEditorCustom one level up from restricted folder. I make the changes in here.
But now i do not know how to make things happened.
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would talk to an WCS expert.   As part of your IBM Software Support agreement, you can open a PMR and ask what is the best way to do the above.   Also I'm assuming you've seen and gone through the Open Laszlo WCS tutorials right?  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.management-center_customization.doc/tutorial/ttfmcmain.htm

Comment: Ok, so there is no a clear answer ... is just an advice to address the question to IBM Software Support. My question is who deserve the answer.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are asking.. if you open the ticket with IBM software support, you'll get the answer.